# How to call method in java from c# code?

Tags: c#, java, android, integration

I have written a method in android(java) i.e. is used to upload image to the server. I want this method to be called from c# code. How to go about i have no idea, the java code follows below?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     Button buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

     buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            request.addProperty("imageName", imageName );
            request.addProperty("base64String", compressedImageString);
            //request.addProperty("compressedImageBitmap", compressedImageBitmap);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            try {

                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

                if(result != null)
                {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getProperty(0).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                else
                {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

          } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
     });

  buttonBrowse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBrowse);
  buttonBrowse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(position!= null){
                showPopup(MainActivity.this, position);
            }           
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private void showPopup(final Activity activity, Point position) {

            int popupWidth = 120;
            int popupHeight = 130;

            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.popup);

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

             popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_popup, linearLayout);

             popupWindow = new PopupWindow(activity);
             popupWindow.setContentView(popupView);
             popupWindow.setWidth(popupWidth);
             popupWindow.setHeight(popupHeight);

             int offset_X = 85;
             int offset_Y = 5;

             popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
             popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, position.x + offset_X, position.y + offset_Y);

        }
    });     
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){

    int[] location = new int[2];
    buttonBrowse.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    position = new Point();
    position.x = location[0];
    position.y = location[1];

}

public void buttonGallery_Click(View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);
}

public void buttonTakePhoto_Click(View v){
        TakePhoto();
}

@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
           Intent intent){

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  

         selectedImageUri = intent.getData();
         selectedImageRealPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
         String path = selectedImageRealPath;
         imageName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1, path.length()); 
         imageSelected = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImageRealPath);
         final ImageView imageViewPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto);
         imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(imageSelected);
         compressedImageString = imageCompression(selectedImageRealPath); 

        }
        break;

    case CAMERA_REQUEST:
    try
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            selectedImageRealPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
            imageSelected = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImageRealPath);
            final ImageView imageViewPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto);
            imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(imageSelected);
            compressedImageString = imageCompression(selectedImageRealPath);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        break;
    }   

    popupWindow.dismiss();  
}

private void TakePhoto() {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    imageName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, imageName);
    selectedImageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            values);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedImageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

}

private String imageCompression(String filePath) {
    File imageFile = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try
    {
      fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile); 
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 600, 300, false);
    scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, baos );
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    //byte[] imageByte = imageString.getBytes();

   return imageString;
```

}

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri)
{
    try
    {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    }
}
```

}

I want to call the method on buttonBrowse from c#

Comment: Why you want to call Andoid-Java code in C#? Android code will only work on Android OS (i.e. on phones, tablets). On the other hand .NET/C# code will will only run on Windows OS (also on Linux if your are using MONO). What is the environment where the C# code will run?

Comment: I have made a website earlier in which there is a HTML 5 page(in asp.net mvc) which contains a browse button(it selects image from the Hard Disk). Now, i'm making an android application that will run website and replaces the browse button with the above button.(that allows to choose image from gallery or Take Photo).I will replace the button with javascript, But i'm not sure how to call the java method.

Comment: What do you mean by "making an android application that will run website"? The android application will have a 'web control' that you can use to browse the web, or you want to host ASP.NET MVC in your android application?

Comment: The website i have made in MVC is for applying loan online. In one of the page there is an option to upload the document by browsing the local hard disk. The client(who have purchased the above website) have now requested for an application(android application). This application runs the website with a small change that, the browse button should allows to browse gallery or take photo from camera of the document. This functionality should be provided dynamically if the website is run from android phone.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call java code  directly from C# code.

You can wrap java classes as COM

See the link below

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0045.html

Comment: There is also http://www.ikvm.net/ that allows some sort of interop between java and .net, for example you can convert and reference java libraries from .net/mono project.

Comment: But ikvm.net source file is over 40 MB. Please suggest me some other alternative to this.